# Spring ConfigurationProperties not loading values(default) from application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

PropertyLoader class does not load the default value for "testValue" from application.yml

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my-property")
@Component
public class PropertyLoader {

    String testValue;

    public String getTestValue() {
        return testValue;
    }

    public void setTestValue(String testValue) {
        this.testValue = testValue;
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: default
my-property:
  testValue: random
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@Value(„${testValue}“)` over testValue field.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Comment: @Value is not required while using ConfigurationProperties

Answer (score 0):

Answering my on question as I figured it out after spending some time on it.
Never set active profile in application.yml, in my case someone added active profile to default, as soon as the spring property loader sees the spring.profiles.active it searches for application-{avtive-profile}.yml, in my case application-default.yml since it does not find a file by that name it does not load the default values from application.yml

Comment: That’s actually not entirely correct — application.properties always gets loaded it is just a profile specific application properties overrides values defined in it as well - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files-profile-specific

Comment: @JAsgarov that statement is true in case the profile is passed as runtime argument, but if you specify an active profile in application.yml then values from application.yml will not be loaded, intact if you inspect the Environment object you will not find the property source application.yml.

Comment: You are right it is explained here point 54.6 https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: Also have the same problem. Removing active.profile from application.yml does not work for me. Default file (application.yml) is still ignored / skipped. Any more ideas?